# How to print last modified time of a file using | in BASH?

Tags: command-line, bash, stat

I am a novice in BASH coding. Is there any way I can print last modified time of a file (say photos) to a text file named last-modified.txt

I tried searching around a bit and could accomplish the task using the following code

```
stat -c %y photos >> last-modified.txt
```

However, I want to use `|` to accomplish the task

EDIT: The aforementioned command (involving `>>` or append) works well but I was curious to know if I can accomplish the same result by something like `stat -c %y photos | cat last-modified.txt` (Although I know this won't work but you get the idea what I am trying to achieve here).

Comment: touch does not display time just change it.

Comment: What is wrong with your command, it should work well? Please describe more what you need instead. And why do you say `>` in the title and `<` in the body of your Question? Also, what does `touch` has to do with it.

Comment: @pLumo I made the relevant edits. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: `stat -c %y photos | cat >> last-modified.txt` should work (you just forgot the `>>`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tee`:

> **tee** - read from standard input and write to standard output and files

Append to file:

```
stat -c %y photos | tee -a last-modified.txt
```

or overwrite file:

```
stat -c %y photos | tee last-modified.txt
```

This is especially useful if you (1) want to keep the output on the screen or (2) need to  write to a file using `sudo`, then you can use `... | sudo tee ...`

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: @RaghavKumar, you could accept the answer by click on the gray tick at its left side.